# Как сделать круг, внутри которого будет показана часть закрытого изображения?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Всем здравствуйте!
На Canvas есть какое-то изображение, которое закрыто черной картинкой. Нужно сделать круг, внутри которого часть закрытого изображения будет просматриваться. При этом круг можно масштабировать, тем самым увеличивая/уменьшая радиус видимой области.
Думаю, что это делается с помощью шейдеров, но пока не могу найти чего-то похожего. В основном написано про работу с 3d фигурами. Я в этом новичок и буду признателен, если ко всему вы еще посоветуете хорошие статьи на эту тему. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

- `Obj1` Создаёте черный квадрат размера картинки.
- `Obj2` Поверх квадрата создаём `Image` с кругом и добавляем компанент `Mask`.
- `Obj3` `Image` с картикой делаем дочерним объектом маски `Obj2`.

Проблемы. В месте с перемещением круга будет двигаться и картинка, поскольку она дочерняя и нужно будет контролировать её позицию и скеил в ручную.